# Heisenbug when doing an ansychronous read from socket

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, boost-asio

I'm calling async_read on a domain socket and my problem is that sometimes I get data and sometimes I don't, even though the remote system always returns data. I seem to be able to read from the socket if I do step-by-step debugging. If I automate unit tests they seem to run too fast for data to be returned, which is odd since the whole purpose of asynchronous methods is to wait for a reply.

I have these as properties of my class:

```
io_service run_loop;
stream_protocol::socket connection_socket;
datagram_protocol::endpoint domain_socket_ep;
vector<unsigned char>read_buffer;
```

I do a write:

```
void operator>>(const vector<unsigned char> input, shared_ptr<Socket>socket) {
  asio::async_write(socket->connection_socket, asio::buffer(input),   std::bind(&Socket::write_handler, socket, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
  socket->run_loop.reset();
  socket->run_loop.run();
}
```

In the write callback I do a read:

```
void Socket::write_handler(const std::error_code &ec, const size_t size) noexcept {
  const size_t avail = connection_socket.available();
  if (!read_buffer.empty()) {
    read_buffer.clear();
  }
  asio::async_read(connection_socket, asio::buffer(read_buffer, avail), std::bind(&Socket::read_handler, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
}
```

I tried wrapping the read function in a `while(read_buffer.size() < avail)` but that just threw me into an infinite loop.

I'm definitely missing something here, I just can't figure out what and the fact that this works when running under step-by-step just makes it worse.

Comment: What is the allocated size for 'input'  and read_buffer?

Comment: Input is sent by the user and in my tests its never empty. read_buffer is set to the number of bytes in the socket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the read side of things:

You never mention the type of `read_buffer`. There's not a lot we know about what `.clear()` does, but if it does what the name suggests, it will be invalid to use `asio::buffer(read_buffer, avail)` without prior `read_buffer.resize(avail)`

---

Why do you have

```
void operator>>(const vector<unsigned char> input, shared_ptr<Socket>socket) {
  asio::async_write(socket->connection_socket, asio::buffer(input),   std::bind(&Socket::write_handler, socket, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
  socket->run_loop.reset();
  socket->run_loop.run();
}
```

Instead of e.g.

```
void operator>>(const std::vector<unsigned char> input, std::shared_ptr<Socket> socket) {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    size_t transferred = boost::asio::write(socket->connection_socket, boost::asio::buffer(input), ec);
    socket->write_handler(ec, transferred);
}
```

If you don't want asynchronous operations, don't use them. That's at least a lot simpler. The following sample would be sane (if you make sure `io` lives longer than any socket that uses it):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5e01c9204255185)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

struct Socket {
    boost::asio::io_service& svc;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket connection_socket;

    Socket(boost::asio::io_service& svc) : svc(svc), connection_socket(svc) {}

    void write_handler(boost::system::error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
    }
};

void operator>>(const std::vector<unsigned char> input, std::shared_ptr<Socket> socket) {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    size_t transferred = boost::asio::write(socket->connection_socket, boost::asio::buffer(input), ec);
    socket->write_handler(ec, transferred);
}

int main(){
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    auto s = std::make_shared<Socket>(io);

    std::vector<unsigned char> v { 100, 'a' };
    v >> s;
}
```

Comment: my writes are fine, it's the reads that fail. read_buffer is defined in the first code block and finally I do want async operations. Why wouldn't I?

Comment: Because you don't use them. As long as you have a single `io_service` with a socket, and `run()` to completion, it's effectively synchronous. If you want asynchrony, the lifetime of the `input` vector is completely inadequate.

Comment: Now that I see the definition of `read_buffer`, it's indeed clear that there was the error. The buffer size is 0, so all the reads get a zero-capacity buffer.

Comment: I've added a size to `read_buffer` and I still can only get it to work with step by step debugging, not with unit tests. I assume the callback is fired when the buffer is full right? If not, what is the pattern to follow? About the lifetime of `input`, I once again have no problems with the writes, only the reads.

Comment: The best pattern is be to [read the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html): they do confirm that the call returns when the socket is closed, the buffer is full or an error occurred. `available()` might not be what you want though (how do you know the response has been received when you invoke it?). Is there a protocol that you're implementing?

Comment: I'm trying to have an object that encapsulates the state machine around a domain socket, where the remote has unknown response times. This still doesn't explain why things work when I debug step by step and not when running unit tests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126749/discussion-between-ruipacheco-and-sehe).